# Swiper.js for switching between html pages

Tags: html, swiper.js

I am trying to use swiper.js to make my html pages swipable.
I have three html pages: 'main page', 'user profile page' and 'content page'.
Reading the swiper.js documentation the examples only show how to swipe  e.g. photos in a div. Hence I have no clue on how to swipe html pages.

**My question:**
Should all three html pages actually just be one html, but seperated within a div each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replicate your pages as individual slides and use Hash/History Navigation (see [demo](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/25-hash-navigation.html)), but the downside is that your content will not be very accessible to users as the Swiper code hijacks a lot of touch controls within the container.

You would be better off using something like [smoothState.js](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js).

Comment: Okay. Appreciate your advice!